# Can I override Authorizations for asp.net core with different Roles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] // only admin
public class XController : Controller 
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Employee")] // only employee
    public ActionResult ActionX() { ... }
}
```

Only admins can access the controller and only employees can access that method, I know that this structure is not the best example but I just would like to know if this is possible! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You absolutely can - but for your own sanity (and other developers) I would switch the `Employee` role to be at the `Controller` level (least permissive) and then have the more restrictive authorization on your action-by-action basis.

Straight from the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#adding-role-checks).

> You can further limit access by applying additional role authorization attributes at the action level:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, PowerUser")]
public class ControlPanelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetTime()
    {
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult ShutDown()
    {
    }
}
```